# Copy XML node to a XML nodes collection (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, copy

I have several XMLs with data from one movie and I want to make one XML with all the movies.. how can I do it?

It is an example of the movie XML:

```
<movie>
<popularity>0.018</popularity>
<translated>true</translated>
<adult>false</adult>
<language>en</language>
<original_name>Return to Rajapur</original_name>
<name>Return to Rajapur</name>
<alternative_name>Retorno a Rajapur</alternative_name>
<type>movie</type>
<id>80261</id>
<imdb_id>tt0444415</imdb_id>
<url>http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/80261</url>
<overview>
A doomed love affair blooms against the beautiful and exotic backdrop of the deserts of India in this romantic drama. Samantha Hartley (Kelli Garner) is a woman in her early twenties who travels to Rajapur in India to visit a resort where her mother stayed years ago. While tracing the steps of her mother, Sara (Lynn Collins), Samantha learns the true story about her mother's stormy marriage to Jeremy (Justin Theroux), a charming but moody alcoholic. Only a few days after their wedding, Sara began to wonder if marrying Jeremy was a mistake, and while visiting India on their honeymoon, Sara met Jai Singh (Manoj Bajpai), a handsome and sensitive widower living in Rajapur. Jai Singh, who speaks fluent English, soon strikes up a friendship with Sara that quickly grows into a romance, but both are aware of the transgressive nature of their love, and their affair takes a tragic turn, leaving its scars on all parties involved.
</overview>
<votes>0</votes>
<rating>0.0</rating>
<tagline/>
<certification/>
<released>2006-11-01</released>
<runtime>97</runtime>
<budget/>
<revenue/>
<homepage/>
<trailer>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2bc8dHUco4</trailer>
<categories></categories>
<keywords></keywords>
<studios></studios>
<languages_spoken>
<language_spoken code="en" name="English" native_name="English"/>
<language_spoken code="hi" name="Hindi" native_name=""/>
</languages_spoken>
<countries></countries>
<images>
<image type="poster" url="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w92/tPuPbPCg0cAwWAAasVAyy4366BA.jpg" size="thumb" width="92" height="136" id="4ee0cac57b9aa14e0f00272e"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w154/tPuPbPCg0cAwWAAasVAyy4366BA.jpg" size="w154" width="154" height="228" id="4ee0cac57b9aa14e0f00272e"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/tPuPbPCg0cAwWAAasVAyy4366BA.jpg" size="cover" width="185" height="274" id="4ee0cac57b9aa14e0f00272e"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w342/tPuPbPCg0cAwWAAasVAyy4366BA.jpg" size="w342" width="342" height="507" id="4ee0cac57b9aa14e0f00272e"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w500/tPuPbPCg0cAwWAAasVAyy4366BA.jpg" size="mid" width="500" height="741" id="4ee0cac57b9aa14e0f00272e"/>
<image type="poster" url="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/original/tPuPbPCg0cAwWAAasVAyy4366BA.jpg" size="original" width="1120" height="1660" id="4ee0cac57b9aa14e0f00272e"/>
</images>
<cast>
<person name="Nanda Anand" character="" job="Director" id="589088" thumb="" department="Directing" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/589088" order="0" cast_id="1000"/>
<person name="Lynn Collins" character="" job="Actor" id="21044" thumb="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/berS11tKvXqTFThUWAYrH279cvn.jpg" department="Actors" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/21044" order="0" cast_id="1001"/>
<person name="Kelli Garner" character="" job="Actor" id="17442" thumb="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/tV4nlT3ApNd2iQMN2JGr6uCnoxX.jpg" department="Actors" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/17442" order="1" cast_id="1002"/>
<person name="Justin Theroux" character="" job="Actor" id="15009" thumb="http://cf2.imgobject.com/t/p/w185/hkJ8UaqMacoIiVkqu1AG69cIjMI.jpg" department="Actors" url="http://www.themoviedb.org/person/15009" order="2" cast_id="1003"/>
</cast>
<version>1</version>
<last_modified_at>2011-12-21 11:18:06 UTC</last_modified_at>
</movie>
```

I need a XML something like this:

```
<movies>
<movie>
</movie>
</movies>
```

I'm sure there is a way I can do it, but I'm new on PHP and XML, so I need help!
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a very elegant solution, but it can work: you can read each file and put their content in one file:

```
<?php
$files = array("file1.xml","file2.xml","file3.xml");
$output = fopen("result.xml","w");
fwrite($output,"<movies>");
foreach ($files as $f)
{
    fwrite($output,file_get_contents($f));
}
fwrite($output,"</movies>");
?>
```

Comment: this is a perfectly fine solution *if* there is no xml prolog in the files